# On an HTTP GET, do the headers come in first, following with the body (using the HttpClient library from apache)?

Tags: java, android, http, header, httpclient

**What I am doing**:
 Trying to get familiar with the HTTP protocol and it's implementation.

**My question**:
 Is it possible to get the headers (specifically Content-Length) of an HTTP GET before you    read the actual body?  From what I understand, I could use a HEAD call for that purpose, but am trying to see if it is even required.  Specifically, in the HttpClient commons library (and most other I guess), there are methods to retrieve the response body as a stream.  Is this stream being read from the socket as it's coming in or has it already been buffered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content-length header field is sent in the response header, you can read it before the response body. But sometimes (dynamically generatted content, unbuffered) it can be omitted ([rfc](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)).  This is what happens  when your browser can't display a progress bar while downloading.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP server sends the headers first. Whether the particular HTTP client you're using exposes them ahead of time is a separate matter.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes the headers come in first. Always.

As you mention **HEAD** request will allow the client to fetch only the headers and no content, however via a **GET** request the headers are always available, and arrive before the actual content. However the content-length field is optional for dynamic content, so it may not ever be available.

Depending on your implementation the stream may or may not be buffered at all. But in most cases, when reading via the stream operators, you receive the content in some small buffered unit, usually a line.

Answer (score 0):

The httpclient commons class streams directly from the socket so it does not waste memory.  If the content-length header is passed, you can read it without reading in the whole response body.

See http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html

Answer (score 0):

The headers always come before the body, and the status before the headers. See the [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html), section "4.1 Message Types".

The format of a generic HTTP message is :

```
        generic-message = start-line
                          *(message-header CRLF)
                          CRLF
                          [ message-body ]
        start-line      = Request-Line | Status-Line
```

For a response, start-line contains the Status-Line. It must be followed by the headers, and then the eventual message body.